# UICollectionViewCell with auto layout: how to get rid of UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I try to have a UICollectionViewCell with a dynamic height determined by auto layout.

On the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` I set the `estimatedItemSize` but all my cells are exactly as big as that estimated size. When I do have a larger cell, I get a `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` with `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` set to exactly the height from the estimated size. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: What are your constraints?

Comment: I have several, but the constraints are ok, they are valid and depend on a multiline UILabel inside the cell. An image at the top (fixed height), then two labels (boths with compression and hugging to required) and then a button at the bottom (again, fixed height)

Comment: That is not enough for me to know that you are completely determining both the height and width using internal constraints. However, as my answer tells you, I've never gotten automatic cell sizing to work as advertised anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In general I have found Apple's claim that there is such a thing as "a UICollectionViewCell with a dynamic height determined by auto layout" to be a myth. What I do is implement the delegate method `sizeForItemAt` to do what the runtime ought to be doing, namely, measure the size in accordance with the internal constraints and return that as the desired size.

Comment: For a downloadable example, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p466collectionViewFlowLayout2/ch21p748collectionViewFlowLayout2/ViewController.swift

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I know what Apple says at WWDC. I also know that what they say to do has never worked for me. I have a bug filed on this (and it has been filed for years). It's not my business to explain why Apple keeps lying about this. If you can answer the OP's question, answer it, but I stand by what I have said. Table view cell automatic sizing works fine for me. Collection view cell automatic sizing does not.